# Filtering items within Python dictionary values containing strings of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a new dictionary from the following:

```
{'FOO': "('BAR','BAA'),('CAR','CAA')", 'FOOO': "('BAAR','BAAA'),('CAAR','CAAA')"}
```

I want to retrieve items within the strings of tuples in the dictionary values, and create a new dictionary using the original keys and the retrieved items as corresponding values. The retrieved items must be by placement (first item of every tuple). The completed dictionary should look like the following:

```
{'FOO': ('BAR','CAR'), 'FOOO': ('BAAR','CAAR')
```

This should be relatively easy, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse those strings. Then it's just a matter of pulling out the right elements.

```
d = {'FOO': "('BAR','BAA'),('CAR','CAA')", 'FOOO': "('BAAR','BAAA'),('CAAR','CAAA')"}
d2 = {k: zip(*ast.literal_eval(v))[0] for k,v in d.iteritems()}
# d2 is now {'FOO': ('BAR', 'CAR'), 'FOOO': ('BAAR', 'CAAR')}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will turn each `"('BAR','BAA'),('CAR','CAA')"` into `(('BAR', 'BAA'), ('CAR', 'CAA'))`.

Then you can just do `[0]` to get the first one. Is that all you were missing?

It's worth noting that, as a general rule, if you're using `literal_eval`, you're usually doing something wrong. For example, maybe instead of storing a string literal version of a `tuple`, you can store a JSON array, or a [`pickle`d](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [`marshal`led](http://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) `tuple`.

Comment: Not by a long shot. I wasn't familiar with the ast module, but I'm now very interested to see what else it has.

Comment: @user1185790: Mostly it has stuff for dealing with Abstract Syntax Trees, and only Python ASTs. Very useful for testing out possible language changes—parse Python source into an AST, modify that AST, and compile the result; not all that useful for anything else. But it has a couple of utility functions that are buried there either because you're not encouraged to use them (like `literal_eval`) or because there are better ways to do the same thing (like `get_docstring`).

Comment: Thanks for the information, abarnert. Out of curiosity, why are you not encouraged to use `literal_eval`?

Comment: @user1185790: If you think you need `literal_eval`, it's often a sign that you're using Python literal syntax as a persistence or interchange format, which you shouldn't be doing. It used to be common in PHP, JS, and other languages to use literal syntax and `eval` all over the place, and they wanted to discourage that from becoming common practice in Python. But sometimes you've got Python literal data from some other source that you can't control, in which case, `literal_eval` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be not the best way to do it, but you can solve it with regular expressions.

```
import re

di={'FOO': "('BAR','BAA'),('CAR','CAA')",
      'FOOO': "('BAAR','BAAA'),('CAAR','CAAA')"}

ndi = {}
for k in di:
    ndi[k] = re.findall('\(\'(\w+)\'\,', di[k])
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but you're right, it's not quite the most elegant. Thanks kphilipp